# Javascript converting values into keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I converted values of a certain property of an object from a list into a key/value list.

I am looking for a different syntax or shorter syntax.

```
const lst = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];
const obj = {};
lst.forEach((per) => {
  obj[per.name] = true;
});
console.log('obj', obj);
```

Result:

```
{A: true, B: true}
```

Comment: heh. "more advanced". someone should include an example using with and gotos.

Comment: @KevinB What do you mean?

Comment: You haven't specified what "more advanced" means. That's a very subjective description and could mean anything to anyone. Better/worse performance, easier/harder to read, better/worse efficiency, etc.

Comment: True, I changed it
@KevinB

Comment: Maybe `I am looking for modern approach`?

Comment: i mean... `modern` is subjective too. and a moving target by definition. `efficient` in what way? dev time? code execution? memory usage? a balance of all three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` and spread syntax to add to object, and on array you can `map()` to transform each object to `{[e.name]: true}`.

```js
const lst = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];

const obj = Object.assign({}, ...lst.map(e => ({[e.name]: true})))
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This is as ugly as SED unix syntax. I am sad. I love JS since 1995 and this is no longer JS :(

Comment: @mplungjan but but but, it's "more advanced"! that clearly makes it 600% betterer.

Comment: Haha :) Yes. terseness is great.  Hello world: `++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++
 ..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.` in [BrainFuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#brainfuck)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `array.reduce`, object spread or it's API counterpart `Object.assign`, and computed property names.

```
var obj = lst.reduce((c, v) => ({ ...c, [v.name]: true }), {});
```

It's essentially the following:

```
var obj = lst.reduce(function(carry, value){
  var obj = {};
  obj[value.name] = true;
  return Object.assign(carry, obj);
}, {});
```

Comment: You may want to wrap `{ ...c, [v.name]: true }` in `()`!

Comment: Joseph you code returns :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

Comment: @mehr That's because I don't expect you to copy-paste the answer. Object spread is new syntax, equivalent to `Object.assign` which I did mention in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const lst = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }];
const obj = lst.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.name] = true, a), {});

console.log(obj);
```

The above is a short for the self-explanatory:

```
const obj = lst.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
    return accumulator[current.name] = true, accumulator; // read about comma operator evaluation on MDN
}, {});
```

and:

```
return accumulator[current.name] = true, accumulator;
```

is the same as:

```
accumulator[current.name] = true;
return accumulator;
```

Comment: @Downvoter why???

Comment: In what way is this "more advanced"?

Comment: It's more functional as it's evaluated in one expression!

Comment: that's not more advanced... it's just different.

Comment: @KevinB I think you're blind or something is wrong with your eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use it in a function. I'm not very sure but its works for me.

```
    //In a fucntion
    function asingListinObject(list, obj){
      //if obj comes undefined or null create one
      if(obj == undefined || obj == null){
        obj = {};
      }
      //do the asignment by the list
      list.forEach((i_lts) => {
        //validate if the 'name' exist
        if(i_lts.name != undefined || i_lts.name != null){
          //New: set a diferent value
          if(i_lts.value != undefined || i_lts.value != null){
            obj[i_lts.name] = i_lts.value;
          }else{
            //Set a default value
            obj[i_lts.name] = true;
          }
        }
      });
      return obj;
    }

    const lst = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' },
    { id: 3, name: 'C', value: false }, { id: 4}];

    const obj_ref = {};
    const obj = asingListinObject(lst);
    //works as references
    asingListinObject(lst,obj_ref);


    console.log('Obj_Ref', obj);
    console.log('Obj', obj);
```

as a result, you will have this:

```
    Obj_Ref {A: true, B: true, C: false }
    Obj {A: true, B: true, C: false }
```

Same values because is the same list. I hope this help.